# Cannot get value from nested facebook object

Tags: javascript, express

Facebook callback returns a JSON object to my controller.
In the controller I use the following to get the username:

```
$scope.result.$promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.loggeduser  = data.toJSON();
            $scope.username = $scope.loggeduser.username;
```

This gives the username no problem.
Now I try to get the token

```
$scope.token = $scope.loggeduser.facebook.token;
```

but here I get an error in the console `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined'.`
I can get the nested facebook object with:

```
$scope.facebook = $scope.loggeduser.facebook;
```

but I cannot access the token using `$scope.facebook.token` , I get the same error.
Here is the object in the console:

```
 Object
    __v:0
    _id:"575127a42f05bf7e2077eb39"
    admin:false
    facebook:Object
      id:"279527782390072"
      name:"John Doe"
      token:"EAAHSBbKZC0ZAoBAI"
     __proto__:Object
    username:"John Doe"
```

console.dir($scope.facebook) gives:

```
facebook:Object
          id:"279527782390072"
          name:"John Doe"
          token:"EAAHSBbKZC0ZAoBAI"
```

But still no dice in getting the value of the token.

Comment: Have you tried bracket notation - $scope.facebook['token'] ?

Comment: Getting the value with `$scope.facebook['token']` or `$scope.facebook.token` will make no difference here. Do you get the other property values in object?

Comment: @Andy_D - just tried that and same error. Have also tried $scope["facebook"]["token"]  and $scope["facebook"].token but always "cannot read property token of undefined.

Comment: @Rohit416 I can get all the properties on the 'outer' object but cannot get anything (id, name or token) on the nested inner facebook object.

Comment: That is weird. Try `console.log($scope.facebook.token)` just below the `console.dir($scope.facebook)` statement.

Comment: @Rohit416. Yes that did it - I had to log in again to Facebook and the console.log($scope.facebook.token) worked. Thanks